# hdfview 2.14 java.io.ioexception

Tags: java, hdf5, hdf

While trying to open a .H5 file in HDFView 2.14 I am getting a error of java.io.IOException:Unsupproted fileformat.
How to resolve this issue.
I am using windows 8.1 pro 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You may be running the wrong version of HDFView for your system, just double check that you did install the 64-bit version of HDFView.